# Add class to each div in a container after interval, and remove previous

Tags: jquery, timeout, delay

I'm attempting to add a 'hovered' class to each `<a>` within a div inside a container in turn. There should be a short delay between each class being applied, and as the class is applied to the next div it should be removed from the previous. 
After the same delay the class should be removed from the final div.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('.banner-wrap > div > a').each(function(i){
        var row = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.hovered').removeClass('hovered');
            row.toggleClass('hovered');
        }, 400*i);

    });

});
```

This is half working - but I'm struggling to understand how to delay the first item (currently that one is getting the class on load) and also need a pointer on how to make sure it's removed after the last div has had the class for the same interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var interval = 1000;
    var timerIds = [];
    var links = $('.banner-wrap > div > a');

    $.each(links, function(index, value) {      
        if (index == links.length - 1) {
            timerIds.push(window.setTimeout(function() {
                $('.hovered').removeClass('hovered');
                $.each(timerIds, function(idx, val) { 
                    clearTimeout(val);
                });
                while (timerIds.length) {timerIds.pop();}
            }, interval*(index + 2)));
        }
      
        timerIds.push(window.setTimeout(function() {
            $('.hovered').removeClass('hovered');
            $(value).toggleClass('hovered');
        }, interval*(index + 1)));
    });      
});
```

```css
div {display:block;padding:1em;}

a {display:block; line-height:1em; color:gray;background-color:whitesmoke;border:0.1em solid whitesmoke;transition: all 1s;}
a.hovered {display:block;height:3em;line-height:3em;color:white;background-color:gray;border:0.1em solid black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner-wrap">
  <div>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

Here is a performance test using the various $.each configurations in this consideration. http://jsperf.com/jqueryeach

---

Comment: added support for properly managing the removal of `Timeouts` and the memory of the array used to store the timer ids..

Comment: there are quite a bit of nested functions and scoped variables going on in this.. my first thought was that `timerId` was not going to be accessible in the anonymous function declared for the timeout.. However, it was.. the **alternative** (and my first approach) was to use `bind` and pass in the array referencially.. `[func].bind([argumentName - string], [array]);`.

Comment: added css transition for effect.. :P